# Loading an XML ( from internal project folder )

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-xml

I have issues running my XML that I've placed in a folder ( from my project ) 
If my XML is at the root of my Solution it will work

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("actionInfo1.xml");
```

But if I place it into my folders ( from my project ) with this syntax the XML won't be found

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");
```

error is :

> Could not find file.....

I've also checked my XML to copy itself to the output folder if it's newer. 
I am a bit confuse because I've loaded CSV's in a similar way without any fuss.

Comment: U need the relative path of your xml file if i understand correctly right ?

Comment: yes I do. the ..\folder1\myfile.xml isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("~\ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");
```

**Edited**

Try this one if it is windows application

```
string strAppPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(strAppPath +"ActionCol\\actionInfo1.xml");
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/47rbot
Thanks for the answer, but I get this ~ in the URL and it won't find my file, have a look over the printscreen

Comment: Is it a web application or windows ?

Comment: Windows application - Coded UI Test Project written in C#

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when your program runs, it searches for the file in the bin debug folder. So u have to see where the program starts looking

For example.,

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");
```

is actually

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"bin\Debug\ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");
```

So if you got you're file in the folder ActionCol u have to do this

```
private XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\ActionCol\actionInfo1.xml");
```

Let me know if this fixes you're problem

Comment: Well when I start my test ( app ) it will copy the XML to the output directory. I have to make it to search there somehow. ( I've tried your suggestion and it's not working)

Comment: What do you mean by output directory ? Custom directory?

Comment: Have you checked if the file is actually transferred ?